# how to use rickshawgraph of django dashing?

Tags: django, coffeescript

I'm trying to use this widget extension for [django-dashing](http://django-dashing.readthedocs.org/)

https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023

It uses `*.coffee` and `*.scss`

I don't use any of them and having trouble using the extension.

(I tried googling to convert *.coffee file to *.js but it complains about `Dashing` is not defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension you have linked to is for Dashing: http://dashing.io/ and you are using django-dashing which is a totally separate project inspired by Dashing. Widgets for the two projects are not compatible so you would have to port the extension you have found for django-dashing.